# How to connect to iccube from Powerquery

Tags: powerquery, iccube

the connection using Excel works fine, but trying the same using PowerQuery does not seems to work, is it supported ?

Comment: maybe with ?msrs in the url like for Reporting Services, https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/integration/reporting_services.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iccube is not directly supported, no. (We typically support sources with buttons in the ribbon.)

It looks like iccube supports an Analysis Services connection interface: https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/integration/excel.php

If connecting with the "Analysis Services" button doesn't work, maybe the Power Query OleDb connector with the OleDb Analysis Services driver would work?

Comment: We're happy to provide you with any help needed from our side, feel free to contact us support at iccube.com

Comment: @carl , when i connect using olebd, i get an error saying we don't support multidimensional ?